# Difference sizeof in C++ Classes with virtual parameter

Tags: c++, class, virtual, sizeof

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class CoolClass
{
   public:
      virtual void set(int x){x_=x;};
      virtual int get(){return x_;};

   private:
      int x_;
};

class PlainOldClass
{
   public:
      void set(int x){x_=x;};
      int get(){return x_;};

   private:
      int x_;
};

int main ()
{
   printf("CoolClass:\t %ld \nPlainOldClass:\t %ld \n",
          sizeof(CoolClass),sizeof(PlainOldClass)); 

   return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
CoolClass:   16 
PlainOldClass:   4
```

and I would like to know why this happen, I tried to find some information about virtual, but I dont understand it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because classes that have virtual functions are usually implemented by the compiler via a [virtual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), see also [this explanation](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/). And to use such virtual table, they  store internally a pointer to the table. In your case, the size of `CoolClass` is given by the size of the `int` member (usually 4 bytes), plus the size of the pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the architecture: 32 bit vs 64 bit). You see 16 due to padding.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a `virtual` member function, the compiler allocates space to hold a pointer to a virtual table. In your case, the size of a pointer looks to be 8. To keep the alignment of the objects at 8 bytes, the compiler adds 4 bytes of padding to the object, which total up to 16 bytes.

Had the compiler not added the padding, `sizeof(CoolClass)` would have been 12.

For the second class, the size is obvious.